# How to change the background of the navigation bar of a single view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have an application with multiple views and the main navigation bar has a background defined in AppDelegate.m . I want one of these views to have different background.

I've tried to embed the whole view in a navigation controller but with no luck. Also I've tried to change the background from the view controller class but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can share the code that would be really helpful. Below might help

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
```

Comment: How does this change the nav bar background for a single view? If you push another view controller, the nav bar will still have this same image.

Comment: you can change it from viewWillDisappear method  @rmaddy

Comment: @AlaaAgwa I understand that. I'm simply pointing out that it doesn't seem like this answer, as written, actually answers your question.

Comment: To implement on specific UIViewController, create a parent of all UIViewController used in your app like BaseViewController. Implement BaseViewController viewWillAppear for default navigation bar throughout app as above. And finally add above code in viewWillAppear in specific view controller. This should solve your problem.